# oData Method to post Image

Tags: odata

I have an OData service and would like expose a method that accepts a byte array as an image that I can de-serialize on the server side and save. I created a method like this:

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/PutImage", Method = "POST")]
public string PutImage(byte[] upE)
{
   string ret = "Good";
   //De-Serialize here.
   return ret;
}
```

I also set the configuration for this method like this:

```
config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("PutImage", ServiceOperationRights.All);
```

I believe this will work on the service side but I am unsure of how to call this from the client side.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OData (and WCF Data Services) don't support service operations like you have above. First of all the UriTemplate is ignored or not allowed. Second of all the parameters to the service operation are passed always in the URL, never in the body. So even though the above might work, you probably don't want to serialize the entire image file into the URL (the server would very likely reject such large URL anyway).
The way to handle binary/large streams in OData is to use Media Link Entries/Media Resources, or the new Named Streams.

There's a great walkthrough how to implement and use MLE/MR here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2010/08/04/data-services-streaming-provider-series-implementing-a-streaming-provider-part-1.aspx, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2010/09/08/data-services-streaming-provider-series-part-2-accessing-a-media-resource-stream-from-the-client.aspx

The Named Streams are similar in the new CTP - described here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2010/11/12/named-resource-streams.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use *POST* in combination with odata: http://protsyk.com/cms/?p=287